# X forwarding Raspberry Pi to Ubuntu Gnome (Desktop)

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding

I have installed Ubuntu Mate on Raspberry Pi. Now, I want to X forward from Raspberry Pi to my Linux Ubuntu Gnome.

I am able to SSH to Pi (Ubuntu Mate) from my desktop (Ubuntu Gnome).

As, I am running Pi in Non-GUI mode, I want to X forward from Pi to Ubuntu Gnome. Need your help in achieving this.

Regards,
Ananda

Answer (score 0):

In order to forward X, you need to have it installed. You also need installed Desktop Environment. XFCE seems to be working best for X-forwarding, from what I read online (I use 3rd party software for that)

so go ahead and install xfce on your raspberry Pi:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce
```

Aptitude should include xorg in the install as a dependency and install along and then you're ready to rock & roll.

Then you just need to login from your Gnome desktop machine into the Pi:

```
ssh -X user@host xfce-session
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the Pi using

ssh -X user@my-raspberrypi-ip

And when you are connected launch GUI applications

nohup firefox &